# React Native bluetooth SPP

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

I try to use SPP on react native, but I don't know the library I have to use.
I try with react-native-bluetooth-serial and serial-next, and react-native-ble-manage,  react-native-ble-plx, but I can't find my device SPP.

What is the library I have to use with SPP ?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the device that you are trying to connect? I've successfully established a serial connection between raspberry pi's integrated Bluetooth and my Android phone using the `react-native-bluetooth-serial-next` library.